# How to record/get memory requests that Last-Level Cache sends to Memory Controller?

Tags: caching, memory, request, simulator, cpu-cache

When there is a LLC miss, the memory request is sent to the MC to get data from memory.

Are there any tools that can get information (address/[read or write]/accurate timing) of the memory request sent by the LLC to the MC?
I want this information to be an input for my MC simulator, so that I can schedule them.

I used a tool called [pin](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) before. But it only records virtual memory addresses and can't get accurate timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no tools to get information from the memory requests sent by the Last-Level Cache (LLC) to the Memory Controller (MC) in a physical processor. [Intel processors have hardware counters that allow for monitoring requests to DRAM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/monitoring-integrated-memory-controller-requests-in-the-2nd-3rd-and-4th-generation-intel), but no information about the address is available, its purpose is to count the number of requests.

You can use full system simulators like [Simics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simics) or [M5](https://sourceforge.net/projects/m5sim/) to generate memory request traces with timing information. You can also get back to Pin and attach a cycle-accurate CPU simulator, but you will have to model the logical-physical address translation.